# Displaying widget one by one in Kivy, Phyllotaxis in Python

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I made phyllotaxis effect.

It works like this:

1. Cycle through whole loop (i.e 15000 iterations).
2. Do the calculations.
3. get the values X and Y.
4. Print all points (ellipses) with values calculated in step 1.

What I want to achieve.

1. One cycle through loop.
2. do the calculations for point 1.
3. get the values X and Y.
4. Print point with values X and Y from one iteration.

N step. N'th cycle through loop.

N+1 step. do the calculations for point N.

N+2 step. get the values X and Y.

N+3 step. Print point with values X and Y from one iteration.

Here is my code:

```
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import (Rectangle, Ellipse, Line
import math

n = 0
c = 5
class PhyllotaxiswApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return boxOustide()
class boxOustide(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(boxOustide, self).__init__()
        with self.canvas:
            global n
            global c
            window_center_x = self.get_center_x() * 8
            window_center_y = self.get_center_y() * 6
            post = c * 3500
            for i in range(15200):
                a = n * 137.3
                r = c * math.sqrt(n)
                x = r * math.cos(a) + window_center_x
                y = r * math.sin(a) + window_center_y
                Color(n % .999, .999, .999, mode='hsv')
                Ellipse(pos=(x, y), size=(5, 5))
                n += 1
if __name__ == "__main__":
    PhyllotaxiswApp().run()
```

**EDIT 1**

Ok so there is huge window opened now for me, after I discovered this:

```
Clock.schedule_interval(class.function,1 / 60)
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried implementing it with the Clock object found in kivy.?